# req.flash() requires sessions and logout destroy session

Tags: node.js, express, session, logout, flash-message

`req.flash()` **requires** sessions and **logout** have to  **destroy** session

**Question**:
How to manage both of these at same time.
when we trying to logout we have to destroy the session which is required for req.flash and this gives an error?

For example: I am not able to use **req.session.destroy()** when I am using **req.flash()**.

Support the Answer with Details...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't have to destroy the session when a user logs out.

Comment: I beg to differ. If I suspect that someone else has captured my session cookie, I want to log out and be sure that the session is destroyed so that the other person cannot use the captured session cookie to get into my session.